# Program will output "Invalid Amount, inputted value is less than 100" i don't know how to put that condition

Tags: java

I'm trying to do an ATM like program, but i need to warn the user if they deposited a value less than 100. I just need to put a condition that will output "Invalid amount, inputted value is less than 100"

```java
public static void TransactDeposit(int iNum, int iName, int iBal, int iCol, int accType)
{
    Heading();

    String newBalance = "", depositAmt = "";
    double convAmt = 0.00, accBalance = 0.00;

    System.out.println("\t\t    Enter X to Exit");
    System.out.println("\n\t      Enter Amount to be Deposited: ");
    System.out.print("\t\t\t  ");
    depositAmt = scan.next();

    if (depositAmt.matches("\\d+"))
    {
        if (accType % 100 == 0)
        {
            convAmt = Double.parseDouble(depositAmt);
            accBalance = Double.parseDouble(accountInfo[2][iCol]);
            accBalance = accBalance + convAmt;
            newBalance = String.valueOf(formatter.format(accBalance));
            accountInfo[2][iCol] = newBalance;
        }
        else if (accType == 1)
        {
            convAmt = Double.parseDouble(depositAmt);
            accBalance = Double.parseDouble(newAccount[2][iCol]);
            accBalance = accBalance + convAmt;
            newBalance = String.valueOf(formatter.format(accBalance));
            newAccount[2][iCol] = newBalance;
        }
        System.out.println("\n\t\t    Deposited: " + depositAmt);
        System.out.println("\n\t----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n\t        Press Enter to Go Back...");
        scan.nextLine();
        if (scan.nextLine() != null)
        {
            ClearScreen();
            AtmMenu(iNum, iName, iBal, iCol, accType);
        }
    }
    else if (depositAmt.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
    {
        ClearScreen();
        AtmMenu(iNum, iName, iBal, iCol, accType);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n\t----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n\tInvalid Key! Press Enter to Try Again...");
        scan.nextLine();
        if (scan.nextLine() != null)
        {
            ClearScreen();
            TransactDeposit(iNum, iName, iBal, iCol, accType);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting the value to `double`, check if it is less than `100`. If so, print error message and either abort or call recursively. Else, continue to update account.

Note, I have removed the regex and have replaced with try/catch.

```java
    // ....

    // Check special case first
    if (depositAmt.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
        ClearScreen();
        AtmMenu(iNum, iName, iBal, iCol, accType);
    }
    else {
        try {
            double convAmt = Double.parseDouble(depositAmt);
            if (convAmt < 100) {
                System.out.println("Invalid amount, inputted value is less than 100");
                ClearScreen();
                TransactDeposit(iNum, iName, iBal, iCol, accType);
                return;
            }
            // User input OK. Can continue...
            // Code to update account removed for brevity....
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
            System.out.println("\n\t----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n\tInvalid Key! Press Enter to Try Again...");
            scan.nextLine();
            ClearScreen();
            TransactDeposit(iNum, iName, iBal, iCol, accType);
        }
    }
}
```